# .ptw Video conversion

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, video-processing

On Video recording with IR camera, a file in .ptw is obtained. I want to analyze the file using standard software, like MATLAB. However, video processing in MATLAB requires the file to be converted to some standard formats like .avi or .mp4 or .wmv files. Please provide a way to make similar conversions, with the help of a software tool or any matlab function etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way I know of to convert their .ptw format to an standard video format is by using FLIR's ResearchIR software:  http://www.flir.com/thermography/americas/us/view/?id=51371

ResearchIR also supports exporting to `.mat` files too.

Hope that helps,
Andy

Answer (score 1):

There is an open-source solution to be used with Python: [Pyradi: an open-source toolkit for infrared calculation and data processing](http://proceedings.spiedigitallibrary.org/proceeding.aspx?articleid=1390590), SPIE Proceedings, Edinburgh, 24-27 September, C. J. Willers, et al. [The PyRadi toolkit (version 1.1.0, 2016-11-20)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyradi) is a Python toolkit to perform optical and infrared computational radiometry (flux flow) calculations:

> The PyRadi toolkit is a Python toolkit to perform optical and infrared
>   computational radiometry (flux flow) calculations.
>
> - Data manipulation (e.g., file input/output, interpolation, spectral quantity conversions, reading Flir Inc PTW files)

Fro Python, Matlab code is not far far away. And you can call Python from Matlab.